# passing nginx variable as command line argument to nginx custom module

Tags: nginx, lua

I wrote a custom nginx module that takes in 3 command line arguments . I would now like to pass the 3rd argument **as a nginx variable** . However passing the nginx variable , causes the module to read the variable name as the argument.

This works:

```
 custommodulename '4' '52.20.206.180' '1' ;
```

This doesnt:

```
    set $a '4';
    custommodulename '4' '52.20.206.180' a;
```

This doesnt as well:

```
    set $a '4';
    custommodulename '4' '52.20.206.180' $a;
```

Both the above cases , the module reads the third argument as 'a' and not '4' !

What I am trying to do:
I'm trying to parse request body and pass in one of the values to my module. 
I am doing this inside the location context.

```
location = /test1{
         client_max_body_size 100k;
        client_body_buffer_size 100k;
        lua_need_request_body on;
        set $a 'eeeeeeee';
        access_by_lua_block{
        package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/usr/local/openresty/lualib/?.so";
        local cjson = require( "cjson" );  -- Include the Corona JSON library
        local body_table = cjson.decode(ngx.req.get_body_data());
        local name = body_table["username"];
        ngx.var.a = name;
        }
        echo $a;
        custommodulename '4' '52.20.206.180' a;
        echo "hi";
        echo $ip_address;
        }
```

The output for the curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"152.134.20.1","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:80/test1

152.134.20.1
hi
```

$ip_address is variable holding result of my module. It doesnt get printed because my module reads the 3rd argument as 'a' and hence throws error.

**How do i pass a nginx variable as argument to a nginx module ?**

Comment: Can't you just do `custommodulename '4' '52.20.206.180' $a`;

Comment: Sorry , I did that . I will edit my question .

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that if you want to accept variables like that, you actually have to process them as such in the module itself (or at least tag that value is being able to come from a variable). For example look around here:http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#lb-registration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to do is with something called ngx_http_compile_complex_value_t. Basically you define a variable of type ngx_http_complex_value_t in your module config struct.

```
typedef struct {
    char *featureCode;
    char *netAcuityServerIp;
    char *ipaddress;
    ngx_http_complex_value_t *ipaddress;
} ngx_http_netacuity_conf_t;
```

When your custom function is called , you use ngx_http_compile_complex_value to set the value of that argument that was passed in as a variable :

```
 static char *ngx_conf_set_str_custom(ngx_conf_t *cf, ngx_command_t *cmd, void *conf)
{
    ngx_http_netacuity_conf_t *config = (ngx_http_netacuity_conf_t *)conf;
    ngx_http_compile_complex_value_t  ccv;

    ngx_str_t *value = cf->args->elts;

    ngx_memzero(&ccv, sizeof(ngx_http_compile_complex_value_t));

    ccv.cf = cf;
    ccv.value = &value[3];
    ccv.complex_value = config->ipaddress;

    config->featureCode = (char *)(value[1].data);
    config->netAcuityServerIp = (char *)(value[2].data);
    //config->ipaddress = (char *)(value[3].data);
    if(ngx_http_compile_complex_value(&ccv) != NGX_OK) {
            return NGX_CONF_ERROR;
        } 
    return NGX_CONF_OK
}
```

To put that value into the variable in your config struct:

```
ngx_http_netacuity_conf_t *nac = ngx_http_get_module_loc_conf(r, ngx_http_netacuity_module); //get configuration struct
if (ngx_http_complex_value(r, nac->ipaddress, &query) != NGX_OK)
        {
             ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0,"ERROR");
        }
```

Now the variable nac->ipaddress has the value that was passed as a variable argument to my module directive !!

Links that I used :

http://www.nginxguts.com/2011/01/working-with-cookies/

https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module/blob/master/src/ngx_http_redis2_handler.c

https://github.com/openresty/redis2-nginx-module/blob/master/src/ngx_http_redis2_module.h